# Use Google Drive like S3 or gcs

Tags: google-drive-api

Is it possible to use google drive like google cloud storage or s3 through API? I mean if I have say have 10TB of test/sensor data on my google drive and I want to do distributed processing on it in the cloud, what are my options?

Comment: Google Drive focuses on storage.  I highly doubt that it offers processsing.  You will just have to stick to cloud servers.  What is the framework/programming language you are going to use for processing logic?

Comment: I see. I kinda guess that but I wanted to be sure. Several lang but it should be independent from lang anyway.

Comment: You don't say what format the data is in. If it's held in Google Spreadsheets, then the spreadsheets API might work for you.

Comment: They are binary files of any format, not google spreadsheets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Drive is optimized for file storage for consumer and enterprise users. It's not a good fit for storing big data or doing lots of processing. Take a look at [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/products/cloud-storage/) instead.